# Which type of Exception is this in java : Note: Demo.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details

Tags: java, exception, compiler-errors

```
import java.util.*;

class Demo {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        TreeSet t= new TreeSet();
        t.add("A");
        t.add("B");
        t.add("z");
        t.add("Z");
        t.add("M");
        t.add("N");
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

`Demo.java` uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint: unchecked for details*

While compiling I got this Error

Comment: This is not exception, this is a warning, compiler is complaining about  TreeSet instance. Always specify types for example TreeSet<String> t= new TreeSet<String>(); .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an error but a warning.

The class `TreeSet` is a parametrized class (`TreeSet<T>`) but you're declaring it raw, meaning you're not specifying the type of your entries.

This means that the compiler cannot infer the type and cannot make any check on what you put into it.

### Correct way of declaring parametrized classes:

If you declare with the type:

```
TreeSet<String> t = new TreeSet<>(); //<-- the compiler knows you will add strings
t.add("someString"); //<-- fine
t.add(1); //<-- won't let you compile
```

... the compiler will enforce the type check and won't let you compile if, by mistake, you're adding something that is not the type you declared.

### The way you're doing (raw type declaration):

If you don't declare the type (like you're doing now):

```
TreeSet t = new TreeSet(); //<-- the compiler cannot know what you will add
t.add("someString"); // <-- fine
t.add(1); // <-- fine... but is it really fine?
```

... then it won't complain when you add whatever inside it. However, this may lead to bugs and that's why the compiler warns you about you're doing something which is not correct.

> As a side note: this is not true just for `TreeMap<T>`, but for any parametrized class/interface which is declared without inferring the parameter(s) type(s)

Comment: Also note that ```t.remove(1)``` will compile either way. For historic reasons ```remove``` takes ```Object``` as an argument. That's a bit of a mean pitfall in Java.

Comment: @geanakuch yes, but at least it's just returning a boolean saying false since the set doesn't contain integers. It is a pitfall indeed, but not too harmful in this example

Comment: yes, i agree. It's not strictly relevant for this example but I deemed it worth mentioning ;-)